# How would society be different in a world with RPG elements?

Tags: alternate-reality, games, rpg

It would be a world that parallels our own on quite a few aspects. There would be roughly 500 different stats for every person (standard stats like strength, intelligence, luck, and also ones like reputation, honour, and curiosity) jobs would be partially defined by classes, everyone would have a level and exp, errands become quests that give exp that would scale based on the necessity from the perspective of the giver, the difficulty of the task, and the lack of obligation.

Achievements would also grant exp, and it would be granted for accomplishments, such as being born, finishing puberty, graduating school, having a child, living 5,10,25,50,75,100+ years, getting married, ruling a village/town/city/province/nation/empire/continent/world, and also more evil ones such as publicly humiliating someone, killing your first person, etc.

There would also be two kinds of people: NPCs and PCs. NPCs have some special powers such as: vendors can go 'On Duty' which prevents them from being attacked, and can sell things to players without risk, NPCs are the only ones that can issue quests, and they can also become Tour Guides, giving tutorials to players.

PCs would be able to enter 'Rivalry' with another PC whose values are incredibly different from their own, but only if they're of a similar level, which makes their levels scale with each other, they can receive quests, probability is distorted giving them bizarre circumstances and more likely to come across people they've met before, and it's more likely to be relevant when they do. A select few 'Main Characters', have special powers that costs them something, such as being able to do things like 'Pause', 'Save', and 'Continue'.

How would this affect society dynamics?

Comment: Relevant question: [How could a society be based off of the rules/conventions of an RPG?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/45872/how-could-a-society-be-based-off-of-the-rules-conventions-of-an-rpg)

Comment: If I may turn this around... can you think of a society dynamic that *wont* be dramatically altered by this system?  It seems that, by changing everything in society, you will make everything in society different...

Comment: the three manga: Konosuba, Dungeon Meshi, and Is It Wrong To Try To Pick Up Girls In A Dungeon?, each deal with this in their own way so they might be worth checking out. One popular idea is that NPC's and first level PC's are the same thing, PC's by doing certain things gain levels becoming more powerful but also become targets of other PCs.

Comment: I understand that this is rather broad, and there are several different ways this could go, but this is the case for the vast majority of questions. Questions on how species could have evolved, how planets could exist in certain ways, feasible ways for galaxies and stars to be a certain colour, why am I in this situation, are all very open ended, and revolve around certain factors that the people answering them could hardly have known, and must be edited to fit the story. The same is the case here.

Comment: This is also potentially a duplicate.  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/46379/leveling-up-as-a-cultural-societal-function/46402#46402

Answer (score 2):

There are two assumptions I make that I asume exist in this world: scarcity exists and people can check each others stats.

By that logic PC's will compete for the Quests and items NPC's sell. And because you can check each others stat they will be the primary form of judgement, making unsociable behavoir an extreme taboo while raising competition because of near limitless intel on someone's capabilities.

Games are made to incentivize people and so in this world people will get obsessed with leveling stats and getting rewards from quests. They will likely try to get as close to main characters as possible.

Have you seen Black Mirror: Nosedive(S3E1)? The concept of that episode is more focused on judgement on social media but it comes close to this idea and will be a nice case study.

Answer (score 0):

If NPCs are only safe from harassment while "on duty", they would quickly become slaves/victims to the PCs of dubious moral character.